# Nodejs + rails + Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, node.js

I am using Rails as my API server and nodejs for serverside rendering with angular js. when I make some post request to API or PUT , Delete request to API, do I need to call it from Nodejs or from frontend?. Which is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are correct; its just a matter of your architecture design.

I would typically **not** call my APIs through NodeJS due to added complexity, unless it is really necessary.